# TextView background not displaying

Tags: android, user-interface, background

I've been working on an app, and I have a problem.
I am trying to get a textview with a background to move above my current screen. The preview renders it correctly, however the emulator and my device both don't show it.
Here is my code -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp" tools:context=".Inspection"
android:baselineAligned="false">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nativeuser_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.aadevs.thetabapp.NativeUserFragment"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_nativeuser" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/otheruser_fragment"
        android:name="com.aadevs.thetabapp.OtherUserFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_otheruser" />
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingBottom="60dp"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/debtcircle">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hey there"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my code for the drawable debtcircle -

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="ring">
<stroke
    android:width="2px"/>
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Here are the different renders (preview, emulator and device)
[image: The android studio preview]

[image: The android emulator preview]

[image: Nexus 5 device view]

As you can see, the preview works fine, however the emulator and device are not working as expected.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is problem in your drawable.... you should use below drawable...

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
   <stroke
    android:width="2dp"
     android:color="strokeColorHere"/>
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
  </shape>
```

give the stroke color if you want...just use it...